# Custom Panel on the map as a Google maps control

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use a `bootstrap` panel as a `google maps` custom control,I have used this html(obtained from the handlebars template used in my js:

[This is an image of the behaviour that I have,the glyphicon I used for the control icon is too small and is visible as a blue speck](http://i.picasion.com/pic78/8360e36fbe7f00983c354c68a41d5dcc.gif)

[I built a fiddle for this but it does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/d54aqx8k/2/)

```
    <div>
      <a href="#sample-panel" data-toggle="collapse">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"> </span>
      </a>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="collapse panel-collapse" id="sample-panel"> 
            <div class="panel-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ornare dolor sit amet erat interdum porttitor. Aliquam eget quam enim. Morbi ut justo porttitor, pellentesque velit vitae, mattis erat. Phasellus molestie turpis ante, a luctus nibh porta quis. Nulla quis malesuada ex. Nam sapien neque, volutpat vel semper vitae, hendrerit ut elit. Cras efficitur orci non ultricies commodo. Integer dictum luctus diam, tempus mollis lectus tristique ac. Cras dapibus quam eros, sed viverra justo elementum a. Etiam enim est, consectetur ac ex ut, lobortis ultrices nisi. Donec viverra mauris nec tellus luctus, vitae finibus mauris tincidunt.

                Nunc laoreet enim sed sem luctus iaculis. Praesent sem arcu, condimentum fermentum facilisis non, egestas at dolor. Vivamus at augue nisl. Integer in volutpat augue. Quisque blandit ullamcorper arcu. Morbi vehicula lobortis velit, nec cursus sapien accumsan ac. Etiam a lorem ut felis sodales dapibus sed vel lacus. Sed lorem lectus, maximus id velit.
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I added it to google maps as a customControl like this:

```
function createControl(el, map) {
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(el.get(0));
}      

//initialize
var $testControl=$('<div>'+Handlebars.templates.gmaps_panel_partial({
    id:"sample-panel",
    isCollapsible:true
})+'</div>').css("width","25%");
```

I find that the panel naturally opens down to the right of the control and collapses back to the top-left.Is there anything I can do for the panel to open down to the left of the control and collapse back to the top-right(i.e the opposite of current behaviour)?